# $Av = 0\iff v \perp\mbox{ rows of }A$. Why is this the case?

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is to better my general understanding of the proof of the following theorem:

Theorem: Let $A$ be an m x n matrix. Let $W = \mbox{Rowspace}(A) = \mbox{Span}\{\mbox{rows of A}\}$. Then $W^{\perp} = \mbox{Nullspace}(A) = \mbox{Kernal}(A) = \{v\in\mathbb{R}~|~Av = 0\}$.

Proof: $v\in\mbox{Nullspace}(A)\iff Av = 0\iff v\perp\mbox{ rows of }A\iff v\in W^{\perp}$

I don't see where the middle '$\iff$' comes from, i.e. I don't understand why $Av = 0\iff v \perp\mbox{ rows of }A$.

Any clarification would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A=\begin{bmatrix}r_1\\r_2\\...\\r_m\end{bmatrix}$, then $Av=\begin{bmatrix}r_1\cdot v\\r_2\cdot v\\...\\r_m\cdot v\end{bmatrix}=0\iff r_i\cdot v=0$ for $1\le i\le m$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_j$ , $j\in \{1,\ldots,m\}$ denote the rows of $A$.
$$Av=0 \Longleftrightarrow \left(\begin{array} &A_1\\ A_2\\ \vdots\\ A_m\end{array}\right) v =\left(\begin{array} &0\\0\\ \vdots\\ 0\end{array}\right )\Longleftrightarrow A_j \cdot v=0 \text{ for } j\in 1,\ldots m $$
$$\Longleftrightarrow A_j\perp v \text{ for } j\in 1,\ldots m $$

Comment: Any other ios 8.2 user who sees the parentheses shifted down?

Comment: I also had problems in firefox during the creation. It only looks finde if I add a & sign to the first and only to the first row. I haven't tried the matrix environments though.

Answer (score 1):

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose that $Av=0$. From the definition of matrix multiplication the $i$-th component of the zero vector is obtained by the scalar product from the $i$-th row of the matrix $A$, that we call $A_i$, and the vector $v$, i.e 
$<A_i,v> = 0$ for all $i=1 \ldots m$. So the vector $v$ is orthogonal to all rows of matrix $A$.

($\Leftarrow$)The vice versa follows as above.